# populate JavaScript object with all the elements from another object

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to have a object like below:

```
var attrs = {
    price       : [0, 500000],
    housesize   : [0, 40],
    lotwidth    : [0, 30],
    storeys     : 'both',
    bedroom     : 0,
    bathroom    : 0
};
```

But I dont want to hard code this and would like to generate automatically from the elements of another object. The object looks like this:

```
var Defaults = {
      steps             : [10,3,3],                                 // steps for the slider to jump 
      filters           : {
        rangeFilter     : ['price',  'housesize', 'lotwidth'],      // list of slider inputs 
        radioFilter     : ['storeys'],                              // list of radio inputs 
        increamentFilter: ['bedroom', 'bathroom'],
      }
};
```

So I am trying to build an object whose keys will be all the values of the `filters` object. The reason I want to do this is because if I add some value to the `filters` object, I would not need to create a key in `attrs` object. The numbers of keys in the `attrs` object is exactly same as the elements in `filters` object.

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers.

==========================================

## ************ EDIT ******************

This is what I came up with at the moment

```
var attrs = {};
for (var key in Defaults.filters) {
   var obj = Defaults.filters[key];
   for (var prop in obj) {
      attrs[obj[prop]] = 0; 
   }
}
```

But at the moment I am adding 0 to all the keys of the new element. I need to come up with a way to add specific values to it dynamically. May be another object inside range filter ??

Comment: Iterate over the properties of `Defaults.filters` and iterate over the  each value (the arrays). Then add each value in the array to the object. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use this snipped for such tasks:

```
function deepCopy(obj) {
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') {
    var out = [], i = 0, len = obj.length;
    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
        out[i] = arguments.callee(obj[i]);
    }
    return out;
}
if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    var out = {}, i;
    for ( i in obj ) {
        out[i] = arguments.callee(obj[i]);
    }
    return out;
}
return obj;
}
```

from: http://snipplr.com/view/15407/